# Action Script 3.0: Move Movieclip file to another project;

Tags: actionscript-3

me and friend are working together to create and rpg game. And i ask my friend to make an opening animation which the file format that he gave me is .gif . then, when i put that file to my project, it adds bunch of bitmap(1000+) in the library that make the size of our project a lot bigger. so, i asked him again to remake it but on another project(.fla) in a movieclip. So, my problem is how i'm going to tranfers that movieclip to our main project?

p.s. we're using AdobeFlashProfessional CS6. Sorry for my bad english.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your friend makes animation in fla and complies it into swf movie.
2. You import the swf movie into your project's library (File -> Import to Library)
3. In the library, you assign this movie a class name like OpeningMovie
4. You can use it in your code as

> ```
> var opening_movie:OpeningMovie = new OpeningMovie();
> addChild(opening_movie);
> ```

You will probably want to know when the movie has ended so you can continue:

```
opening_movie.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkOpeningEnd, false, 0, true);
stop();

function checkOpeningEnd(evt:Event) {
    var mc:MovieClip = evt.target as MovieClip;
    if (mc.currentFrame == mc.totalFrames) {
       mc.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkOpeningEnd, false);
       mc.parent.removeChild(mc);
       mc.stop();
       play();
    }
}
```